# How to mutate a Vec<u16> in a struct in a DoubleStorageMap?

Tags: pallet, storage

How do I mutate a `DoubleStorageMap` with a `Vec<T::AccountId>` as a value using a struct?

```rust
Data::<T>::mutate(
  id.clone(),
  user_id.clone(),
  |params: &mut DataParams<T::AccountId>| {
    params.users.push(new_user);
    params.total_users += 1;
  }
);
```

`total_users` doesn't increase but `users` only ever has one user.

---

What's the best way to accomplish this? The `mutate` is within a for loop and needs to append multiple users.

Comment: are you mutating for every `new_user` in some vector/array `users`?

Comment: it's new data that resets and needs to restore every so often. i just retested it and actually `total_users` doesn't increase.

Comment: Okay im not sure what's happening, if the build is not compiling correct.  but now its pushing in the data. maybe i need to clean it up

Comment: Please include all the types that are involved in your question, most importantly `DataParams`.

Comment: Moreover, please be aware that iterating over a map, if the map keys can be unbounded is a dangerous operation.

Comment: @kianenigma unbounded as in possibly infinite? There are limitations to who and how often this can be done so that would solve that issue

Comment: @bobbydy unbounded as in may produce a block that exceeds the PoV or ref time limit. It is strongly advised to bound how many items can be iterated on in a single extrinsic.